# PHP Structure To Create An Array Within Array (JSON)

Tags: php, json

I am currently building an API for an Android Application and my PHP skills aren't too hot. The API I am trying to create returns Pet Adoption listing from a specific city and that result is paginated. In isolation, this part works fine. What has me stuck is the Promoted Adoption listings. Both the adoptions and promoted adoptions come from different MySQL tables.

The current code (posted below) returns the data like this:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "totalPages": 2,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "adoptions": [{
            "adoptionID": "1",
            "petTypeID": "1",
            "petTypeName": "Dog",
            "breedID": "126",
            "breedName": "German Shepherd Dog",
            "userID": "9",
            "userName": "Siddharth Lele",
            "cityID": "172",
            "cityName": "Pune",
            "adoptionName": "Test Pet #1",
            "adoptionCoverPhoto": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/zen-pets-4c786.appspot.com/o/Adoption%20Covers%2Ftest_pet_9?alt=media&token=553e1159-4a0b-4514-ba49-d0698b76b925",
            "adoptionDescription": "Just testing the new adoption creator to check how the content fits with the new layout. Now checking how it handles multiple lines in the Adoption listing's description...",
            "adoptionGender": "Male",
            "adoptionTimeStamp": "1529302079",
            "adoptionStatus": "Open"
        },
        {
            "adoptionID": "2",
            "petTypeID": "2",
            "petTypeName": "Cat",
            "breedID": "289",
            "breedName": "Abyssinian",
            "userID": "9",
            "userName": "Siddharth Lele",
            "cityID": "172",
            "cityName": "Pune",
            "adoptionName": "Test Pet #2",
            "adoptionDescription": "Just testing the new adoption creator...",
            "adoptionGender": "Female",
            "adoptionTimeStamp": "1529302079",
            "adoptionStatus": "Open"
        }
    ],
    "totalPromoted": "12",
    "totalPromotionPages": 4,
    "promotionPageNumber": 1,
    "promotions": [{
            "promotedID": "3",
            "adoptionID": "3",
            "optionID": "3",
            "paymentID": "pay_ARtc4aZ7V1M69o",
            "promotedFrom": "2018-06-26",
            "promotedTo": "2018-07-26",
            "promotedTimestamp": "1529996304",
            "petTypeID": "1",
            "petTypeName": "Dog",
            "breedID": "126",
            "breedName": "German Shepherd Dog",
            "userID": "9",
            "userName": "Siddharth Lele",
            "cityID": "172",
            "cityName": "Pune",
            "adoptionName": "Test Pet #3",
            "adoptionDescription": "Just testing the new adoption creator...",
            "adoptionGender": "Female",
            "adoptionTimeStamp": "1529302079",
            "adoptionStatus": "Open"
        }
    ]
}
```

The PHP Code is:

```
$queryCount = $conn->prepare('
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalAdoptions 
    FROM adoptions_test 
    INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
    INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
    INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
    INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
    WHERE adoptionStatus = \'Open\' 
    AND adoptions_test.cityID = ?');
$queryCount->bindParam(1, $cityID);

if ($queryCount->execute()) {
    $adoptionCount = $queryCount->fetch();
    $response = array();
    if ($adoptionCount != null) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["totalAdoptions"] = $adoptionCount["totalAdoptions"];

        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoptions_test 
            INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
            INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
            INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
            INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
            WHERE adoptionStatus = \"Open\" 
            AND adoptions_test.cityID = ? 
            LIMIT " . $offsetNumber . ", " . $itemsPerPage);
        $query->bindParam(1, $cityID);

        if ($query->execute()) {
            $response = array();
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["totalPages"] = ceil($adoptionCount["totalAdoptions"] / $itemsPerPage);
            $response["pageNumber"] = ceil($pageNumber);

            $adoptions = $query->fetchAll();
            if ($adoptions != null) {
                $response["adoptions"] = array();
                foreach ($adoptions as $adoption) {
                    $tmp = array();
                    $tmp["adoptionID"] = $adoption["adoptionID"];
                    $tmp["petTypeID"] = $adoption["petTypeID"];
                    $tmp["petTypeName"] = $adoption["petTypeName"];
                    $tmp["breedID"] = $adoption["breedID"];
                    $tmp["breedName"] = $adoption["breedName"];
                    $tmp["userID"] = $adoption["userID"];
                    $tmp["userName"] = $adoption["userName"];
                    $tmp["cityID"] = $adoption["cityID"];
                    $tmp["cityName"] = $adoption["cityName"];
                    $tmp["adoptionName"] = $adoption["adoptionName"];
                    $tmp["adoptionCoverPhoto"] = $adoption["adoptionCoverPhoto"];
                    $tmp["adoptionDescription"] = $adoption["adoptionDescription"];
                    $tmp["adoptionGender"] = $adoption["adoptionGender"];
                    $tmp["adoptionTimeStamp"] = $adoption["adoptionTimeStamp"];
                    $tmp["adoptionStatus"] = $adoption["adoptionStatus"];
                    array_push($response["adoptions"], $tmp);
                }

                $queryPromotedCount = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalPromoted 
                    FROM adoption_promoted 
                    INNER JOIN adoptions_test ON adoption_promoted.adoptionID = adoptions_test.adoptionID 
                    WHERE adoptions_test.cityID = ?
                    AND CURDATE() BETWEEN promotedFrom AND promotedTo');
                $queryPromotedCount->bindParam(1, $cityID);
                if ($queryPromotedCount->execute()) {
                    $promotedCount = $queryPromotedCount->fetch();
                    if ($promotedCount != NULL) {
                        $response["totalPromoted"] = $promotedCount["totalPromoted"];

                        $queryPromoted = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoption_promoted 
                            INNER JOIN adoptions_test ON adoption_promoted.adoptionID = adoptions_test.adoptionID 
                            INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
                            INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
                            INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
                            INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
                            WHERE adoptions_test.adoptionStatus = \"Open\" 
                            AND adoptions_test.cityID = ? 
                            AND CURDATE() BETWEEN promotedFrom AND promotedTo 
                            LIMIT " . $promotedOffsetNumber . ", " . $promotedItemsPerPage);
                        $queryPromoted->bindParam(1, $cityID);
                        if ($queryPromoted->execute()) {
                            $response["error"] = false;
                            $response["totalPromotionPages"] = ceil($promotedCount["totalPromoted"] / $promotedItemsPerPage);
                            $response["promotionPageNumber"] = ceil($pageNumber);

                            $promotions = $queryPromoted->fetchAll();
                            if ($promotions != NULL) {
                                $response["promotions"] = array();
                                foreach ($promotions as $promotion) {
                                    $tmp = array();
                                    $tmp["promotedID"] = $promotion["promotedID"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionID"] = $promotion["adoptionID"];
                                    $tmp["optionID"] = $promotion["optionID"];
                                    $tmp["paymentID"] = $promotion["paymentID"];
                                    $tmp["promotedFrom"] = $promotion["promotedFrom"];
                                    $tmp["promotedTo"] = $promotion["promotedTo"];
                                    $tmp["promotedTimestamp"] = $promotion["promotedTimestamp"];
                                    $tmp["petTypeID"] = $promotion["petTypeID"];
                                    $tmp["petTypeName"] = $promotion["petTypeName"];
                                    $tmp["breedID"] = $promotion["breedID"];
                                    $tmp["breedName"] = $promotion["breedName"];
                                    $tmp["userID"] = $promotion["userID"];
                                    $tmp["userName"] = $promotion["userName"];
                                    $tmp["cityID"] = $promotion["cityID"];
                                    $tmp["cityName"] = $promotion["cityName"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionName"] = $promotion["adoptionName"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionCoverPhoto"] = $promotion["adoptionCoverPhoto"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionDescription"] = $promotion["adoptionDescription"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionGender"] = $promotion["adoptionGender"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionTimeStamp"] = $promotion["adoptionTimeStamp"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionStatus"] = $promotion["adoptionStatus"];
                                    array_push($response["promotions"], $tmp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "There are no open Adoptions available. Please try again";
            }

            /** SHOW THE RESULT **/
            $content_type = 'application/json';
            return $result->withStatus(200)
            ->withHeader('Content-type', $content_type)
            ->write(json_encode($response));
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is that the following structure

```
"totalPromoted": "12",
"totalPromotionPages": 4,
"promotionPageNumber": 1,
"promotions": [{
```

to be inside the "adoptions" tag so that the "promoted" array goes inside the "adoptions" array. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will do the trick for you:

```
$queryCount = $conn->prepare('
SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalAdoptions 
FROM adoptions_test 
INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
WHERE adoptionStatus = \'Open\' 
AND adoptions_test.cityID = ?');
$queryCount->bindParam(1, $cityID);

if ($queryCount->execute()) {
    $adoptionCount = $queryCount->fetch();
    $response = array();
    $tempPromotions = array();
    $tempPromotions['promotions'] = array();
    if ($adoptionCount != null) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["totalAdoptions"] = $adoptionCount["totalAdoptions"];

        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoptions_test 
            INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
            INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
            INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
            INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
            WHERE adoptionStatus = \"Open\" 
            AND adoptions_test.cityID = ? 
            LIMIT " . $offsetNumber . ", " . $itemsPerPage);
        $query->bindParam(1, $cityID);

        if ($query->execute()) {
            $response = array();
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["totalPages"] = ceil($adoptionCount["totalAdoptions"] / $itemsPerPage);
            $response["pageNumber"] = ceil($pageNumber);

            $adoptions = $query->fetchAll();
            if ($adoptions != null) {
                $response["adoptions"] = array();
                foreach ($adoptions as $adoption) {
                    $tmp = array();
                    $tmp["adoptionID"] = $adoption["adoptionID"];
                    $tmp["petTypeID"] = $adoption["petTypeID"];
                    $tmp["petTypeName"] = $adoption["petTypeName"];
                    $tmp["breedID"] = $adoption["breedID"];
                    $tmp["breedName"] = $adoption["breedName"];
                    $tmp["userID"] = $adoption["userID"];
                    $tmp["userName"] = $adoption["userName"];
                    $tmp["cityID"] = $adoption["cityID"];
                    $tmp["cityName"] = $adoption["cityName"];
                    $tmp["adoptionName"] = $adoption["adoptionName"];
                    $tmp["adoptionCoverPhoto"] = $adoption["adoptionCoverPhoto"];
                    $tmp["adoptionDescription"] = $adoption["adoptionDescription"];
                    $tmp["adoptionGender"] = $adoption["adoptionGender"];
                    $tmp["adoptionTimeStamp"] = $adoption["adoptionTimeStamp"];
                    $tmp["adoptionStatus"] = $adoption["adoptionStatus"];
                    array_push($response["adoptions"], $tmp);
                }

                $queryPromotedCount = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalPromoted 
                    FROM adoption_promoted 
                    INNER JOIN adoptions_test ON adoption_promoted.adoptionID = adoptions_test.adoptionID 
                    WHERE adoptions_test.cityID = ?
                    AND CURDATE() BETWEEN promotedFrom AND promotedTo');
                $queryPromotedCount->bindParam(1, $cityID);
                if ($queryPromotedCount->execute()) {
                    $promotedCount = $queryPromotedCount->fetch();
                    if ($promotedCount != NULL) {
                        $tempPromotions["totalPromoted"] = $promotedCount["totalPromoted"];

                        $queryPromoted = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoption_promoted 
                            INNER JOIN adoptions_test ON adoption_promoted.adoptionID = adoptions_test.adoptionID 
                            INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
                            INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
                            INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
                            INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
                            WHERE adoptions_test.adoptionStatus = \"Open\" 
                            AND adoptions_test.cityID = ? 
                            AND CURDATE() BETWEEN promotedFrom AND promotedTo 
                            LIMIT " . $promotedOffsetNumber . ", " . $promotedItemsPerPage);
                        $queryPromoted->bindParam(1, $cityID);
                        if ($queryPromoted->execute()) {
                            $response["error"] = false;
                            $tempPromotions["totalPromotionPages"] = ceil($promotedCount["totalPromoted"] / $promotedItemsPerPage);
                            $tempPromotions["promotionPageNumber"] = ceil($pageNumber);

                            $promotions = $queryPromoted->fetchAll();
                            if ($promotions != NULL) {
                                foreach ($promotions as $promotion) {
                                    $tmp = array();
                                    $tmp["promotedID"] = $promotion["promotedID"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionID"] = $promotion["adoptionID"];
                                    $tmp["optionID"] = $promotion["optionID"];
                                    $tmp["paymentID"] = $promotion["paymentID"];
                                    $tmp["promotedFrom"] = $promotion["promotedFrom"];
                                    $tmp["promotedTo"] = $promotion["promotedTo"];
                                    $tmp["promotedTimestamp"] = $promotion["promotedTimestamp"];
                                    $tmp["petTypeID"] = $promotion["petTypeID"];
                                    $tmp["petTypeName"] = $promotion["petTypeName"];
                                    $tmp["breedID"] = $promotion["breedID"];
                                    $tmp["breedName"] = $promotion["breedName"];
                                    $tmp["userID"] = $promotion["userID"];
                                    $tmp["userName"] = $promotion["userName"];
                                    $tmp["cityID"] = $promotion["cityID"];
                                    $tmp["cityName"] = $promotion["cityName"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionName"] = $promotion["adoptionName"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionCoverPhoto"] = $promotion["adoptionCoverPhoto"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionDescription"] = $promotion["adoptionDescription"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionGender"] = $promotion["adoptionGender"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionTimeStamp"] = $promotion["adoptionTimeStamp"];
                                    $tmp["adoptionStatus"] = $promotion["adoptionStatus"];
                                    $tempPromotions['promotions'][] = $tmp;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                array_push($response["adoptions"], $tempPromotions);
            } else {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "There are no open Adoptions available. Please try again";
            }

            /** SHOW THE RESULT **/
            $content_type = 'application/json';
            return $result->withStatus(200)
            ->withHeader('Content-type', $content_type)
            ->write(json_encode($response));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$queryCount = $conn->prepare('
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalAdoptions 
    FROM adoptions_test 
    INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
    INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
    INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
    INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
    WHERE adoptionStatus = \'Open\' 
    AND adoptions_test.cityID = ?');
$queryCount->bindParam(1, $cityID);

if ($queryCount->execute()) {
    $adoptionCount = $queryCount->fetch();
    $response = array();
    if ($adoptionCount != null) {
        $response["error"] = false;
        $response["totalAdoptions"] = $adoptionCount["totalAdoptions"];

        $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoptions_test 
            INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
            INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
            INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
            INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
            WHERE adoptionStatus = \"Open\" 
            AND adoptions_test.cityID = ? 
            LIMIT " . $offsetNumber . ", " . $itemsPerPage);
        $query->bindParam(1, $cityID);

        if ($query->execute()) {
            $response = array();
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["totalPages"] = ceil($adoptionCount["totalAdoptions"] / $itemsPerPage);
            $response["pageNumber"] = ceil($pageNumber);

            $adoptions = $query->fetchAll();
            if ($adoptions != null) {
                $response["adoptions"] = array();
                $refs = Array();
                foreach ($adoptions as $adoption) {
                    $tmp = array();
                    $tmp["adoptionID"] = $adoption["adoptionID"];
                    $tmp["petTypeID"] = $adoption["petTypeID"];
                    $tmp["petTypeName"] = $adoption["petTypeName"];
                    $tmp["breedID"] = $adoption["breedID"];
                    $tmp["breedName"] = $adoption["breedName"];
                    $tmp["userID"] = $adoption["userID"];
                    $tmp["userName"] = $adoption["userName"];
                    $tmp["cityID"] = $adoption["cityID"];
                    $tmp["cityName"] = $adoption["cityName"];
                    $tmp["adoptionName"] = $adoption["adoptionName"];
                    $tmp["adoptionCoverPhoto"] = $adoption["adoptionCoverPhoto"];
                    $tmp["adoptionDescription"] = $adoption["adoptionDescription"];
                    $tmp["adoptionGender"] = $adoption["adoptionGender"];
                    $tmp["adoptionTimeStamp"] = $adoption["adoptionTimeStamp"];
                    $tmp["adoptionStatus"] = $adoption["adoptionStatus"];
                    $refs[$adoption["adoptionID"]] = &$tmp;
                    array_push($response["adoptions"], $tmp);
                }

                $queryPromotedCount = $conn->prepare('SELECT adoption_promoted.adoptionID,COUNT(*) AS totalPromoted 
                    FROM adoption_promoted 
                    INNER JOIN adoptions_test ON adoption_promoted.adoptionID = adoptions_test.adoptionID 
                    WHERE adoptions_test.cityID = ?
                    AND CURDATE() BETWEEN promotedFrom AND promotedTo
                    GROUP BY adoption_promoted.adoptionID');
                $queryPromotedCount->bindParam(1, $cityID);
                if ($queryPromotedCount->execute()) {
                    $promotedCount = $queryPromotedCount->fetchAll();
                    if ($promotedCount != NULL) {
                        foreach($promotedCount as $promoted)
                        {
                            $adoptionID = $promoted["adoptionID"];
                            $refs[$adoptionID]["totalPromoted"] = $promoted["totalPromoted"];

                            $queryPromoted = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM adoption_promoted 
                                INNER JOIN adoptions_test ON adoption_promoted.adoptionID = adoptions_test.adoptionID 
                                INNER JOIN pet_type ON adoptions_test.petTypeID = pet_type.petTypeID 
                                INNER JOIN breeds ON adoptions_test.breedID = breeds.breedID 
                                INNER JOIN users ON adoptions_test.userID = users.userID 
                                INNER JOIN cities ON adoptions_test.cityID = cities.cityID 
                                WHERE adoptions_test.adoptionStatus = \"Open\" 
                                AND adoptions_test.cityID = ? 
                                AND adoption_promoted.adoptionID = ?
                                AND CURDATE() BETWEEN promotedFrom AND promotedTo 
                                LIMIT " . $promotedOffsetNumber . ", " . $promotedItemsPerPage);
                            $queryPromoted->bindParam(1, $cityID);
                            $queryPromoted->bindParam(2, $adoptionID);
                            if ($queryPromoted->execute()) {
                                $response["error"] = false;
                                $refs[$adoptionID]["totalPromotionPages"] = ceil($promoted["totalPromoted"] / $promotedItemsPerPage);
                                $refs[$adoptionID]["promotionPageNumber"] = ceil($pageNumber);

                                $promotionsList = $queryPromoted->fetchAll();
                                if ($promotionsList != NULL) {
                                    $refs[$adoptionID]["promotions"] = array();
                                    foreach ($promotionsList as $promotion) {
                                        $tmp = array();
                                        $tmp["promotedID"] = $promotion["promotedID"];
                                        $tmp["adoptionID"] = $promotion["adoptionID"];
                                        $tmp["optionID"] = $promotion["optionID"];
                                        $tmp["paymentID"] = $promotion["paymentID"];
                                        $tmp["promotedFrom"] = $promotion["promotedFrom"];
                                        $tmp["promotedTo"] = $promotion["promotedTo"];
                                        $tmp["promotedTimestamp"] = $promotion["promotedTimestamp"];
                                        $tmp["petTypeID"] = $promotion["petTypeID"];
                                        $tmp["petTypeName"] = $promotion["petTypeName"];
                                        $tmp["breedID"] = $promotion["breedID"];
                                        $tmp["breedName"] = $promotion["breedName"];
                                        $tmp["userID"] = $promotion["userID"];
                                        $tmp["userName"] = $promotion["userName"];
                                        $tmp["cityID"] = $promotion["cityID"];
                                        $tmp["cityName"] = $promotion["cityName"];
                                        $tmp["adoptionName"] = $promotion["adoptionName"];
                                        $tmp["adoptionCoverPhoto"] = $promotion["adoptionCoverPhoto"];
                                        $tmp["adoptionDescription"] = $promotion["adoptionDescription"];
                                        $tmp["adoptionGender"] = $promotion["adoptionGender"];
                                        $tmp["adoptionTimeStamp"] = $promotion["adoptionTimeStamp"];
                                        $tmp["adoptionStatus"] = $promotion["adoptionStatus"];
                                        array_push($refs[$adoptionID]["promotions"], $tmp);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $response["error"] = true;
                $response["message"] = "There are no open Adoptions available. Please try again";
            }

            /** SHOW THE RESULT **/
            $content_type = 'application/json';
            return $result->withStatus(200)
            ->withHeader('Content-type', $content_type)
            ->write(json_encode($response));
        }
    }
}
```